# volume sizing attached to EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, docker-volume

Inside an EC2 I have docker with a container that I can't lose, so I noticed that I was out of space on the attached and exclusive volume for docker.

So I increased it with another 15GB and executed the commands according to the aws documentation, but my container is not getting this new size.

```
sudo growpart /dev/nvme1n1 1
sudo pvresize /dev/nvme1n1p1
sudo lvextend -L+15G /dev/docker/docker-pool
```

The return of `lsblk`:
[image]

And I noticed that these "dm" are still old, does anyone know what it could be, and how to solve it?

**Considerations**:

1. In `/etc/sysconfig/docker-storage` is already defined `--storage-opt dm.basesize=75GB`
2. `docker system info`

> ```
> Server Version: 19.03.13-ce
>  Storage Driver: devicemapper
>   Pool Name: docker-docker--pool
>   Pool Blocksize: 524.3kB
>   Base Device Size: 75.16GB
>   Backing Filesystem: ext4
>   Udev Sync Supported: true
>   Data Space Used: 67.24GB
>   Data Space Total: 80.38GB
>   Data Space Available: 13.14GB
>   Metadata Space Used: 11.81MB
>   Metadata Space Total: 67.11MB
>   Metadata Space Available: 55.3MB
>   Thin Pool Minimum Free Space: 8.038GB
>   Deferred Removal Enabled: true
>   Deferred Deletion Enabled: true
>   Deferred Deleted Device Count: 0
>   Library Version: 1.02.135-RHEL7 (2016-11-16)
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the problem, in addition to enlarging the disk and performing the manual resizing process mentioned in the question, enable saving the container to a new image with `docker commit` removing the container and then uploading it again, based on the previously saved image, in this way the new container got all the space available on the instance's disk.